# Move button when in Landscape on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, button, landscape

I have a button that is not autoresizing correctly.  I need it moved over about 100 pixels to the right when it is landscape left or landscape right.  Is there an easy way to do this?   I know how to do it with javascript, but not objective c.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your controller implement the viewDidLayoutSubviews method and position your view(s) as you would like.

Comment: How does that help me move a button?

Comment: inside that method you can then determine the location that you would like the button placed and set it accordingly e.g.

Comment: something like this:
`UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
BOOL inLandscape = orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || oritentation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

CGFrame frame = CGRectMake( inLandscape ? 100.0 : 0, 0, myControl.frame.size.width, myControl.frame.size.height );`

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do this the following way, insert the code to move your controls as necessary.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

  if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
    //setup your interface for portrait
    }

else

  if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
  {
  //setup your interface for landscape
  // your code to move buttons etc would go here
  }
}
```